# Rails: Making sure two tables are "sync'd"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Relationships:

- `Team` has many `Rosters`
- `Team` has many `Announcements`

  - `Announcement` has one `AnnouncementRoster`

When creating an `Announcement`, the user must assign a `Roster` to it (whose data will be used to create its new `AnnouncementRoster`).

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roster_players
  has_many :rosters, -> { uniq } ,  :through => :roster_players
  has_many :announcement_rosters, -> { uniq } ,  :through => :announcement_players
end

class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roster_players
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :roster_players
end

class RosterPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :roster_id }
end


class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :announcement_roster
end

class AnnouncementRoster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :announcement_players
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :announcement_players
end

class AnnouncementPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :announcement
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I believe I need different relationship models (`RosterPlayer`, `AnnouncementPlayer`, `TaskPlayer`, etc.) because different relationships require different attributes. For example: an AnnouncementPlayer has a `read?` column, TaskPlayer has a `progress` column, and RosterPlayer has a `captain?` column.

**Question:** 
What is the best way to make sure that the `AnnouncementRoster` is "sync'd" with the `Roster` it was copied from? In other words, if the copied `Roster's` data is changed (a user is added or removed from it) than the corresponding `AnnouncementRoster` should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategies you want to decide between, are:

1. use database-level idioms to cascade those updates (invisibly to rails)
2. Use `after_save` and `after_update`, having Rails push the changes
3. Create non-automatic methods (rake tasks) in Rails to push the updates on a cron
4. Push the changes with SQL scripts living in bash and cron-controlled (or similarly, have the changes sent by pigeon)

Which of these you choose is really dependent on your environment, application metrics, resiliency, etc.

Sorry this is an overview answer.  Someone else can probably talk through the pro-con sides of this and help you make that decision based on yet-unstated info.

Comment: the 'typical' rails app would use approach #2. Not saying thats the best way to do it, but it's certainly very common and very easy.